# How to record audio from playing music player

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

In my application i am playing audio using AvAudioplayer, after playing the audio i have to record the audio from AvAudioplayer and any other external noices along with the audio.

How can i do that.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

use this function to play sounds

```
- (AVAudioPlayer *)getNoteFromFilename:(NSString *)name andoftype:(NSString *)type{
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name
                                                      ofType:type];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AVAudioPlayer *note = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                                              error:nil] autorelease];
return note;
```

and u can call the function like this

```
self.btn_do = [self getNoteFromFilename:@"MusicFileName" andoftype:@"mp3"];
```